# Why adding a second router next to the first router/modem improved the first router's speed?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a Technicolor TG582n router/modem. It has no antennas. The wifi speed on it was super slow between 0.3 to 3.5Mbps while on ethernet it can go up to 10Mbps. The ISP told me that it is because of a noise issue. Since the ethernet speed is much higher, I connected another router to it, tp-link 300M Wireless N Router, and set them on different and well spaced channels. I ended up getting up to 10Mbps as a speed on both routers. I am subscribed to an open-speed plan which should be more than 6Mbps and it never got higher than 12Mbps. I am wondering why the first router/speed got improved so drastically?

Comment: I am not sure there is a scientific wireless explanation - I do not think so. One possibility:  You would very likely have reset the first router during this exercise or it reset itself and then the speed increased because of the reset.

Comment: the description is not really clear, can you make a diagram?

Comment: A modem/router connected to the internet via ADSL cable. From this same modem/router, an Ethernet cable is taken from it and is connected to a second router.
I am not sure what application to use to make a diagram. And no I didn't reset the modem/router. I just plugged in another router thinking that it would increase the speed as it did.